# Adding Variable to URL On Next Page WIth PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect the user to `page2.php` and add `$hash` to the URL

I'm currently using:

```
header("Location: page2.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

which works, but after the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` i would like to add `&when=$hash` to the URL

`$hash` is defined, I just need it to pass on to the next page

Comment: Good, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just concatenate the strings:

```
header("Location: page2.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . "&when=" . $hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the hash value to the session before redirecting and then do the ridirect as you are doing now or embedded it in the URL

With session

```
$_SESSION['when'] = $hash;
header("Location: page2.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Embedding directly in URL

```
header("Location: page2.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."&when=".$hash);
```

Comment: Please review your answer. You do not use ever the `$_SESSION["when"]`

Comment: sorry for mistake, but why that shouldn't be use?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I thought the 2 alternatives related to each other.